# Mirth Connect Script to Re-process Errors?

Tags: mirth

We have to go through and re-process connection-type errors in Mirth Connect.  Is it possible to have a script somewhere that re-processes with these restraints?

- Can't reprocess Transformer Errors
- Can't keep reprocessing connection-type errors when interface is down

I was thinking of a script launched manually that would go through the feeds with errors and reprocess the valid connection-type errors.  Is this possible?

Thank you :)
Todd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're storing the messages, a database reader that connected to mirth's own db could actually do the trick. You'd need to come up with a solution to keep those messages from reprocessing endlessly, though.

Comment: This is exactly what we implemented two years ago, and some pretty big headaches went aways.

Answer (score 1):

Mirth 3.3 has reprocessing option check if its useful for you